# Tool to plot schedule of events

Tags: logging, graph, plot

I have a list of events from a log file with a start and end date and looking for a tool to plot them on a timeline like a task execution schedule, with the event name on the y-axis and the time on the x-axis. It would be great if the plot were scrollable as the number of event is quite large and logging could span several days. Does something like this exist or am I left to implement it myself, maybe in a web browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nicest and most flexible timeline chart that I have found is [simile](http://simile.mit.edu/).  Give it a try.  If you are more prone to developing your own solution on top of a very nice framework I would really recommend [d3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/).